# Recognize native android file

Tags: android, elf

I want to write a file classificator - something like the linux `file` command does. The main feature should be to detect the target OS (especially Android). It has to work on compiled/native files (ELF file format). For executables I currently check the interpreter (`/system/bin/linker`) to guess it is android. For shared objects I do not have such a criteria yet. I there a way to do that?